# on click to a specific a tag I want a below div with other links inside to be shown

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am been stocked on this "simple" trick, I have a navbar with 6 links and if I click on one of them I want a below div with other links to be displayed.
So far I was able to do this "working" but just the first div with the first links is appearing.
If I click on the second link I should be able to display the second div with different links.
Not sure how to archive this and would like to have a clarification if possible.
I am sure I could use siblings or next which I tried to but I also sure I am not using them in a proper way.
Thanks a lot for helping

This is the code so far

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="aetoggle-desktoplist"><span class="icon-myaccount"></span><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                    <li class="aetoggle-desktoplist"><span class="icon-cards"></span><a href="#">Cards</a></li>
                    <li class="aetoggle-desktoplist"><span class="icon-travel"></span><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    <li class="aetoggle-desktoplist"><span class="icon-insurance"></span><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
                    <li class="aetoggle-desktoplist"><span class="icon-rewards"></span><a href="#">Rewards</a></li>
                    <li class="aetoggle-desktoplist"><span class="icon-business"></span><a href="#">Business</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I click on one of them I want these to be displayed( these links inside divs is below the navbar so not in the same parent ) regarding the previous a tag clicked. I just posted 2 of them but there are 6

HTML

```
<div class="aedisplaydiv-belownavbar">
        <div class="aedisplaydiv-belownavbar-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Card Account</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Account Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rewgister for Online Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Activate a new Card</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Support 24/7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Download the Amex App</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Business Account</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">American Express @Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Online Merchant Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">International Payment for Businesses</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Other Accounts</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">International Money Transfer for Card Members</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Cards -->
    <div class="aedisplaydiv-belownavbar">
        <div class="aedisplaydiv-belownavbar-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Personal Cards</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vies Personal Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View Dollars and Euro Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Credit Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Refer friends. Get rewarded.</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Small Business Cards</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View All Business Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Compare Business Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Gold Business Charge</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Platinum Business Charge</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Why American Express for your Business</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Corporate Cards</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find out about our Corporate Cards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Compare Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Enquire about the Corporate Card programme</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li><p>Gift Cards</p></li>
                        <li><a href="#">View Gift Cards</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('.aetoggle-desktoplist').on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var $this = $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar');

$this.slideToggle('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar').next().hide();

});
```

UPDATE

Hi everyone,
I have an actual update, so if i click on the link I have to slideDown the div with the links inside it and if click again to same link I should be able to slideUp the same div (this is working fine so far) but the new thing is if I click on the second link when the first div open the previous one should slideUp first and then the second one should slideDown.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can connect these elements by index.

If you click the first link - the first .aedisplaydiv-belownavbar is the target.

Something like:

```
 $('.aetoggle-desktoplist').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this),
            target = $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar').eq(index);

        $this.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            target.slideToggle()
        });
});
```

Edit:

```
$('.aetoggle-desktoplist').each(function (index) {
        var $this = $(this),
            target = $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar').eq(index);

        $this.on("click", function (e) {


            e.preventDefault();
            // hide others
            $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar is-open').hide()
            // show this
            target.addClass('is-open').show()
        });
});
```

Second Edit:

```
$('.aetoggle-desktoplist').each(function (index) {
                var $this = $(this),
                    target = $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar').eq(index);

                $this.on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var isOpen = $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar.is-open');

                    if (isOpen.length > 0 && !isOpen.is(target)) {
                        isOpen.slideUp()
                        isOpen.removeClass('is-open');
                        target.addClass('is-open').slideDown()

                        return undefined;
                    }

                    if (isOpen.is(target)) {
                        target.removeClass('is-open').slideUp()
                        return undefined;
                    }

                    target.addClass('is-open').slideDown()
                    return undefined;
                });
            });
```

Comment: this is actually "working" but is opening one by one which i want to hide the previous opened if click on a new one but thanks a lot

Comment: sorry mate, literally trying for a while but again not sure what is wrong.
I upvoted your answer because is actually the right one but nearly perfect.
If click on this toggle the slide down or slide up but if opened and click on another one slide it Up and the new clicked one slideDown

Comment: Do u still use .slideToggle()?
You have to use .slideDown() and .slideUp().
Because you exactly know wich target has to slide down and up.

Comment: replace .hide() with slideUp() 
replace .show() with slideDown()

Comment: yes I tried this option but 2 issues, in  your edited code they never slideUp once is opened.
2) Then becuase is-open class is inline with .aedisplay-belownavbar-inner i tried to write $('.aedisplaydiv-belownavbar.is-open').slideUp() and is kind of doing the trick but automaticly slidingDown again.
Thanks

Comment: I actually worked on your first answer and was able to do this 


$this.on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            target.slideToggle().siblings().hide();
});



which is nearly there

Comment: I forgot to remoce the "is-open" class after hiding the element. @MatteoSoresini take a look at my second edit. It should work like that

Answer (score 1):

The way you usually do this usually is by putting the below links into the upper list.

```
<li class="aetoggle-desktoplist">
    <span class="icon-myaccount"></span>
    <a href="#">
        My Account
        <ul>
            <li><p>Card Account</p></li>
            <li><a href="#">Account Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rewgister for Online Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Activate a new Card</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Support 24/7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Download the Amex App</a></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

Script:

```
$('.aetoggle-desktoplist > a').on("click", function (e) {
    $('.aetoggle-desktoplist ul').hide();
    $(this).find('ul').show();
});
```

Comment: yes makes sense but was tricky for the style like this so i preferred to put it outside in separate div, thanks a lot by the way :-)